# Program complies, but while not finish second half. Yahtzee Die based program, Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, dice

Created a program that rolls 5 6 sided dice. I repeat this until a yahtzee. I also keep track of the number of rolls, and I repeat the entire process 1000x. My program works, but does not display anything. Please help me to spot the error thank you. In my last for-loop, when i run the program there is no output display after it? Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/* The DiceTester class simulates the rolling of dice */

public class DiceTester
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       int userInput;                               //Holds user input.
       int sumDice;                             //Holds the sum of the dice.
       int firstDie;                                //Holds value of die 1.
       int secondDie;                               //Holds value of die 2.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  //scanner object for input.

    //Prompt and collect user input.
    System.out.print("Creating two dice. One with 6 sides, enter value for 
    the second die: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Create two dice objects. 
    Die die1 = new Die();               //With default constructor.
    Die die2 = new Die(userInput);      //With argument.

    System.out.println("Generating dice ...");
    System.out.println(die1);   //Show state of dice, toString.
    System.out.println(die2);

    System.out.println("Rolling the dice ...");

    //Roll Dice. Store value of indiviual dice and sum.
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
    firstDie = die1.getValue();
    secondDie = die2.getValue();
    sumDice = firstDie + secondDie;

    //Display values to screen.
    System.out.println(firstDie + " " + secondDie + " " + sumDice); 

    System.out.println("\nDie1 Die2 Sum");
    System.out.println("-------------");

    //Create for loop that runs 10x and shows value of dice.
    for (int roll = 1; roll <= 10; roll++)
    {
        die1.roll();
        die2.roll();
        firstDie = die1.getValue();
        secondDie = die2.getValue();
        sumDice = firstDie + secondDie;

        System.out.println(firstDie + "    " + secondDie + "    " +     
        sumDice);
    }

    System.out.println("\nGenerating five 6-sided dice ...");

    //Creating 5 more dice.
    Die yahtDie = new Die();
    Die yahtDie2 = new Die();
    Die yahtDie3 = new Die();
    Die yahtDie4 = new Die();
    Die yahtDie5 = new Die();

    //Print state of dice.
    System.out.println(yahtDie + "\n" + yahtDie2 + "\n" + yahtDie3 + "\n" + 
    yahtDie4 + "\n" + yahtDie5);

    int numRoll = 0;    //Holds the number of rolls until yahtzee. 
    int totalRoll = 0;  //Holds the total number of rolls to get yahtzee. 
    double avgRoll;     //Holds the average number of rolls to get yahtzee.
    int maxRoll = 0;            //Holds the maximum number of rolls, yahtzee
    int minRoll = 0;            //Holds the minimum number of roll, yahtzee

    //Create for loop to iterate 1000x.
    for (int roll = 1; roll <= 1000; roll++)
    {
        //Roll dice in while loop.
        while(!(yahtDie == yahtDie2 || yahtDie2 == yahtDie3 || yahtDie3 ==  
        yahtDie4 || yahtDie4 == yahtDie5))
        {
            yahtDie.roll();
            yahtDie2.roll();
            yahtDie3.roll();
            yahtDie4.roll();
            yahtDie5.roll();

            numRoll++;
        }
        totalRoll += numRoll;

        if (maxRoll > numRoll)
            maxRoll = numRoll;

        if (minRoll < numRoll)
            minRoll = numRoll;

    }

    avgRoll = totalRoll / 1000.0; //Total number of rolls to get yahtzee /   
    number of yahtzees.

    System.out.println("Rolling for 1000 yahtzees... \nCounting the number  
    of rolls for 1000 yahtzees... \nFound 1000 yahtzees.");
    System.out.println("The maximum amount of rolls to get a yahtzee: " + 
    maxRoll);
    System.out.println("The minimum amount of rolls to get a yahtzee: " +  
    minRoll);
    System.out.println("The average amount of rolls to get a yahtzee: " +    
    avgRoll);

   }
}
```

Output:

```
Creating two dice. One with 6 sides, enter value for the second die: 5
Generating dice ...
Die[6 sides, value = 2]
Die[6 sides, value = 4]
Rolling the dice ...
4 1 5

Die1 Die2 Sum
-------------
2    6    8
5    6    11
4    2    6
5    3    8
1    3    4
4    6    10
6    6    12
6    5    11
6    5    11
2    1    3

Generating five 6-sided dice ...
Die[6 sides, value = 5]
Die[6 sides, value = 1]
Die[6 sides, value = 3]
Die[6 sides, value = 5]
Die[6 sides, value = 6]
```

die class:

```
import java.util.Random;

/* This class creates a die of n sides and rolls it. */

public class Die
{
    private int numSides; //holds the amount of sides of dice.
    private int faceUp;   //holds the value of the die facing up.

    /* Default constructor creates a 6 sided die and rolls it. */

    public Die()
    {
        //Random newDie = new Random(); //Create random object for the dice.

        numSides = 6;
        roll(); //Assign the value from the random newDice method (1-6) to the current side up.
    }

    /* This constructor creates a die of 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, or 100 sides, and rolls it. */

    public Die(int side)
    {
        //Random newDie = new Random();

        if (side == 4 || side == 6 || side == 8 || side == 10 || side == 12 || side == 20 || 
            side == 100)
        {
            numSides = side;
            roll();
        }
        else
        {
            numSides = 6;
            roll();
        }
    }

    /* The getValue method returns the the current value facing up. */

    public int getValue()
    {
        return faceUp;
    }

    /* This method rolls the dice */

    public void roll()
    {
        Random newDie = new Random();            //Create random object for the dice.
        faceUp = newDie.nextInt(numSides) + 1;   //Assigns random value from 1 to numSides to faceUp. "Simulate dice roll."
    }

    /* This method prints the state of the object. */

    public String toString()
    {
    return "Die[" + numSides + " sides, value = " + faceUp + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: should I screenshot my output?

Comment: grant, if the output is in a console window, don't screenshot it, but copy and paste it as text.

Comment: If you want to? I guess. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Attach `Die` class source.

Comment: That inner `while` loop is going to loop until all 5 die are identical *objects*, which will be *never*.  You should, perhaps be comparing `.getValue()` results.